# How to make <img> clickable in xyz.xhtml so that it will read data from <p> tag in abc.xhtml?

Tags: javascript

xyz.xhtml contains image tag.Which on click should open a div in the same page and display the content form the

tag of other file named abc.xhtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I got the Solution.
You can use the following snippet to access the element from one HTML/XHTML file in another HTML/XHTML file.

function test_fun(){
  $(function(){
    $("#<id of the element in which you want to show to contents>").load("
    <name_of_file> <#ID_of_Element_you_are_accessing>");
  });
}


The space between name of file and ID of element is necessary.
```

Comment: Does this load() method works on any attribute(like id, name, title)?